# GWT Widget Event Handler is Not Working When The Widget Inserted into GWT DIV Element

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, widget

I have a custom widget which is can accept a widget inside of it. Here is the code:

```
public class CustomDivWidget extends Widget {
    protected Element divElement = DOM.createDiv();

    public CustomDivWidget() {      
        divElement.getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PX);
        divElement.getStyle().setHeight(100, Unit.PX);
        divElement.getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);
        divElement.getStyle().setBorderWidth(1, Unit.PX);
        divElement.getStyle().setBorderColor("blue");
        setElement(divElement);
    }

    public void add(Widget child) {
        divElement.appendChild(child.getElement());
    }
}
```

Then this is how I used it:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    CustomDivWidget customDiv = new CustomDivWidget();
    TextButton button = new TextButton("Button 1");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("Button 1 clicked!");
        }
    });
    customDiv.add(button);
    RootPanel.get().add(customDiv);
}
```

When I run it, it show correctly the widget I want like this : 
[image: Custom Widget Element]

But the problem is, the click handler was not working when I tried to click the button. The questions are :

1. Why it is not working?
2. What should I do to make it working?

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are bypassing GWT's event system this way (I'm not sure though). However, why not using a FlowPanel?

```
protected FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();

public CustomDivWidget() {      
    fp.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PX);
    fp.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(100, Unit.PX);
    fp.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);
    fp.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(1, Unit.PX);
    fp.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor("blue");
    setElement(fp.getElement());
}
```

Apart from that, why are you using DOM elements instead of widgets? Using widgets instead of having to deal with the DOM is one of the key features of a toolkit like GWT (just my opinion here).

Edit : try to attach the handler directly to the DOM, to see if it makes any difference :

```
 DOM.setEventListener(button.getElement(), new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
            switch (DOM.eventGetType(e)) {
                case Event.ONCLICK:
                    System.out.println("click");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not working, even when I use FlowPanel, the click event handling not running. I using DOM elements because I need to wrap a div element where I can add some class name (ie. caraousel) and then activate the js library that will turn my div element into some useful widget.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer, check if adding an event listener directly to the DOM works for you.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The solution you offer actually didn't match with what I'm trying to achieve. What I want to achieve is to build a widget where my user could freely adding their widget inside of my widget without losing any event handler that already attached to their widget previously. Any idea how to achieve that? Thanks.